# next.js getInitialProps doesn't work at mobile browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have an app works **perfectly** (with no error) on desktop but when I use **mobile device ** ,I found that all pages **can not trigger** `getInitialProps` method at client side only if i **navigate** through **Link** component

**This My code :**

```
return(
  <>
   <Head>
      <title>
        welcome to Anas Behhari | blogging posts for
        {StaticFunction.Dateit(new Date())} |
        {new Date().getFullYear() - 1 + "-" + new Date().getFullYear()}
      </title>
  </Head>
   
  <div className="main">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-10 offset-lg-1 js-post-list-wrap Blogs-con">
            <h2 className="h4 section-title">
              <span> Latest posts </span>
            </h2>
            {Blogs.map((blog) => (
              <Article blog={blog} key={blog._id} />
            ))}
            {BlogList}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </>
)

blogs.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
 try {
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/blogs?offset=0&max=5");
  const Blogs = res.data;
  return { Blogs };
  } catch (error) {
  return { error };
}
```

};

```
export default blogs;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, if so what are they? Also, could you provide the rest of the code for your `blogs` component (code before the `return` statement)?

Comment: The code before return is not the probem ! but just to let you know when I access for example /blogs from URL it gives me everything like it should be but when I navigate to /blogs through <Link> component it gives an error that the Blogs variable where i store my blogs is undefined. I forgot to mention only on phone !

Comment: Because `getInitialProps` runs both on the server (first page load) and client (client-side navigations) which requires isomorphic code, it is recommended to use [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) instead. Have you tried using that instead?

Comment: Well actually I just change a bit inside the `getInitialProps` function and I get rid of Axios and used the simple `fetch` function and it worked perfectly fast and with no error !!! I'll add the solution down below ! Thank you  @juliomalves for your time I really appreciate it my man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 2 days of searching on the internet I figured out that I just need to change a bit inside the `getInitialProps` function.

> The main factor was to get rid of the `Axios` and replace it with `Fetch` API

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/blogs}`)
    const Blogs = await res.json()
    if(!Tags) return {props:{error:true}}
    return {
     props: {
       Blogs,
     },
    }
}
```

> if this solution didn't work `getServerSideProps` instead of
> `getStaticProps`